# WordPress mobile menu items not showing on mobile view

Tags: wordpress, css

My client's WordPress website I created and selected a menu for  mobile.

It's good on desktop but menu items are not showing on mobile.

Here is website link http://biz236.inmotionhosting.com/~ifbbpr5/

Comment: Try install free plugin and skip dealing the current issue. Less problem, more time for the other tasks. Just an opinion buddy

Answer (score 1):

In your `<div class="mobile-menu">` no items is generated.You should call your menu to that div in your `header.php`.

```
<div class="mobile-menu-area">
    <div class="mobile-menu">
        <?php echo   wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => $atts["your-menu-name"] , 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul  id="your-ul-id" class="your-ul-class">%3$s</ul>' ));
?>              
      </div>
</div>
```